# Creating a Colosseum to hold sports events with good viewer experience and maximum efficiency using up to 16 century tech

Tags: construction, architecture

The background is simple. An emperor wants to create a more splendid colosseum than the one they have but tasks the engineers making it with the following:

- **The court or field is about a 100 by 65 meters.**
- **The underground should be extensive to support the needs of the sports.** Ahm. Like staging mock sea battles. You know. Basic stuff
- **The stadium should protect the viewers from the elements as well as it can be made while also providing enough light so that people can see, and be well ventilated**
- **Viewer comfort and seeing is important**. Important point as they already have another stadium. This one is made to be better but smaller. People should have a better experience here.
- **Heavily decorated and made to be fancy and a sign of wealth and power**. I'm not asking for decoration here but just saying that it is something to be kept in mind. This is not a modern stadium.
- **Lastly it should feel intimate, somehow, people there should feels that the athletes are really close. Athletes also feel that.** This is something I took from watching football, soccer for our American friends, as many teams can tell you that certain stadium are a lot harder to play in with the home supports acting as a huge factor in the home team favor.
- As durable and resilient as possible.
- **Edit**: The capacity should be as many as possible but only as long as it does not contradict the other point. If dropping 10000 seats to the design satisfy the other requirements then sure. If adding them does not hurt then also sure.

Tech is not above 16 century tech. Resources are practically unlimited in time, materials, manpower, or anything else.

**So. What are they making? The overall shape? The capacity? Or whatever else you guys think is important to create that beast**

I hope it can be done. But if not then what is not working?

### Extra fluff

The Colosseum or Flavian Amphitheatre could hold as many as 80000. Modern stadiums can even go as far as 110000 people for something like Sardar Patel Stadium. And the 100000 range is not an issue.

My problem with some of the largest stadiums that they feel cold as well as too modern and both contradict this particular colosseum.

For examples Beaver Stadium or Ohio Stadium are huge but fall into that category.
I much prefer something a lot more smaller and intense like Anfield stadium or a smaller version of San Siro.

Even the original colosseum does not capture the intimacy and magnificent that I'm looking for here. That's why I'm asking and did not just get a number from a stadium I like and picked an overall shape and size and boom we have the new colosseum.

Comment: *"The original colosseum does not capture the intimacy and magnificent that I'm looking for here":* in what way doesn't it satisfy your vision? It *was* magnificent, and very successful. (No, the ruins we have do not resemble it as it was when in use. For example, the marble cladding is gone, as well as the [*velarium*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velarium) which protected the spectators from the sun.) Overall, it is important to specify *in what way* you want to make it more magnificent; and seating capacity is a fundamental design requirement for an arena -- it cannot be left unspecified.

Comment: P.S. The Flavian Amphiteatre was *not* intended for "sports" as we understand them, or any kind of athletic competitions. For that you may want to look at the Constantinopolitan [Hippodrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippodrome_of_Constantinople).

Comment: @AlexP,
added capacity.
I have not really seen the original in it's time, are we even sure what it actually looked like, so I'm only left with the overall structure. It feels a bit too large to be intimate. I also think wood gives a feeling of home more than cold marbles. But I'm not the one making it. So. Whatever you think is best. Think of the new venue as a heavily decorated opera house but enlarged to hold sports events. Do that make it better?

Comment: @AlexP, 
Betrayed by Wikipedia.Impossible.
Anyway thanks

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding this Question. Roman-era technology and ruins obviously demonstrate that what you want can be done. What's the actual question? Would it be more clear if you told us what stadium you like today and ask if it can be recreated using 16th century tech?

Comment: @JBH,
Yes. It can be done.
I'm asking what is the optimal overall solution to my question?
Think of it like this: You go to a car company and ask for a super fancy really fast car with this sound system and a steering wheel made of x and interior cabin of this materials...etc. You are not going for this to ask for a car but a particular product. What we have is usually maximum capacity venues like Beaver. But what if I want to create a very fancy a magnificent arena where you feel like you are in an intimate setting.
I like Anfield, I'm a red, but not even Anfield is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was afraid of. You're asking us to engineer the building. Have you ever been involved with creating architectural drawings? If not, please trust me that you've provided very inadequate descriptions of your needs. What do you need this level of detail for?

Comment: @JBH,
If it breaks any rules then tell me.
I won't discourage more detailed answers but I'm NOT looking for something too specific like floor plants or exact material types.
I want to get the overall feeling of the thing.
Like how much people would an architecture be able to fit around the ring while insuring an intimate, I said it a lot sorry, feeling for each?
That sort of thing.
Does it make sense?

Comment: This is a valid question, it's just not an easy question because "intimate" (regardless your efforts to define it) is subjective. The more people the stadium hosts, the less "intimate" it is by definition because the number of players isn't increasing and 16th c. tech doesn't allow for video. Some of it is trivial (rectangular field = oblong stadium). But more to the point, if you don't need floor plans, then what do you need? It feels like you're asking for a lot but actually need very little.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116229/discussion-between-seallussus-and-jbh).

Comment: @AlexP The colosseum was the place for at least [2 events for which the arena had been flooded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naumachia), and besides gladiatorial combat they held occasionally other events like wrestling as well as just public executions (not the lion type, the head-falling type). [Circus Maximus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circus_Maximus) might be another one that works - seating for 150000 spectators - 50% more than the Hippodrome.

Comment: @Trish: Of course the Circus Maximus works, but the Hippodrome of Constantinople is so much more *emotional*... Sometimes I get the impression that it was the focal point of the social life of New Rome.

Comment: @AlexP it was the focal point for the eastern roman empire due to Justinian iirc. but for sheer size, CM is the more pivotal design, especially in how they solved problems there.

Comment: As JBH said, archaeology proves it can be done and further to that, your 100 by 65 meters is a lot smaller than the real thing…https://www.google.com/search?q=dimensions+of+the+colosseum&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB779GB779&oq=dimensions+of+the+c&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i457j0l4j0i395l2.7576j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin,
Yes. I did mention the original in my answer with the exact number.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin no it's not, the colosseum field is quite smaller than that, around 80x60m. The whole thing is not that big, san siro is huge in comparison, I can believe 80000 people could sit there only because they didn't have modern spaced sits.

Comment: @Carlo I thought the Colusseum had an elliptical plan about 189 meters (615 ft / 640 Roman feet) long, and 156 meters (510 ft / 528 Roman feet) wide, with a base area of 24,000 square metres (6 acres).

(https://www.google.com/search?q=colluseum+dimensions&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB779GB779&oq=colluseum+dimensions&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i13i457j0i22i30l2.10783j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

How is that mistaken?

Comment: that's the plan of the whole building, not the field

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## The design of the arena reflects the use!

### [Amphitheater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphitheatre)

What we call [Colosseum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colosseum) today was once the Flavian Amphitheatre. The ruins we know today reflect in some art the original, but had been used as a quarry and stripped of most decoration. Researchers estimate between 50 and 80 thousand visitors, depending on one crucial fact: Do we count the additional 30000 seats on the steep wooden ranks that were added during use or not? In its original design, it featured fabric roofing for a sizeable portion of the visitors. Its design was ingenious to be made mainly from arches, speeding up construction, reducing costs by magnitudes, and still allowing *every* spectator a good view of the spectacle! Besides the amenities provided by vendors, it was connected to the roman canalization and even was flooded to show off [Naumachia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naumachia) in it.

[image]

Nowadays we still use a building of this design in [Arles: it hosts bullfights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arles_Amphitheatre) but it also was modified in medieval times, making it appear to miss arches. The [Pula Arena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pula_Arena) was restored to the almost original design in the outer walls while the interior was partially remodeled for theatre use. The former Arena measures 67.95 by 41.65 m (222.9 by 136.6 ft).

In its most simple design, the Amphitheater is pretty much a solid dam of dirt with the seating on it, and some access tunnels into the arena for access and at the same time drain it of water during rain. One such example is in [Pompejii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphitheatre_of_Pompeii). This building is known for its near-perfect riot control design and the good sanitary design as it shared its public toilets with the [neighboring wrestling school](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palaestra)!

### [Circus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circus_(building))

Just some miles over was the even larger [Circus Maximus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circus_Maximus), offering seating for 150 thousand people on a long, oblong track. Designed for chariot and horse racing, it provided a much better overview over the whole track than any modern racing arena. In total, the building occupied an area of 621 m (2,037 ft) by 118 m (387 ft). The orientation is off of the East-West and North-South axis, offering as little sun directly into the eye as possible during the races, but the playing of the building did result in rainwater runoff into the flat side of the arena till a proper runoff redirection allowed races even in the worst weather. In contrast to the Flavian Amphitheatre, no source speaks of sun roofing erected here.
[image]

Note that the eastern Romans had *extreme* intimate race events on the hippodrome constructed to house 100000 people: People were so sworn in to "their" team (or rather: Demes - Blue and Green), that they regularly battled each other on the streets, wore their team colors and these sports teams were almost political parties! By the way, I strongly suggest [Extra Credits Justinian & Theodora](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H_2E0RxVHH4&list=PLhyKYa0YJ_5Cfgs7L6XFvcQE_TpyyYiEI) series here, which does shed some light on the phenomenon of the races in eastern Rome in the first part's later half.

### Gymnasium & [Palestra](https://edition-topoi.org/dEbookViewer/bsa_058_07.pdf)

For athletic competitions and footraces, the buildings were usually smaller but similar in design. Events that drew only small amounts of visitors would often be held directly in the training grounds. For example, the aforementioned [Wrestling school in Pompeji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palaestra) was also the place for smaller or tryout wrestling matches that wouldn't be held in the larger theater. The [Palestra in Olympia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palaestra_at_Olympia) featured slightly raised ranks around a square arena in the center, the outer area of which was covered by arcades. [Delphi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palaestra_at_Delphi) featured a similar design. Spectators did have to contend for viewing space here.

Similarly, the [Gymnasia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gymnasium_(ancient_Greece)) and Stadia for athletics often were used for the competitions themselves, allowing spectators to watch from the shaded arcades - or in [Olympia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stadium_at_Olympia) from earthen mounds surrounding the leveled tracks that would house seating during the festival. The only other permanent structure in the Olympia stadium was the judge tribune, the access ditch, and the starting line. The Gymnasium in Olympia, which is a separate place from the Stadium, did feature several terraces of stone for spectators, while [in Delphi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gymnasium_at_Delphi) the access road to the temple above the place had a retaining wall that provided an extra rank for visitors to watch from above while others huddled at the sidelines

### [Theater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_theatre_(structure))

Designed for the consumption of plays and borrowing from the greek design, they are half-circular in design. In contrast to the greek design, the upper rows in the roman design are usually steeper, allowing more spectators.

## Best intimate design?

To achieve the wanted intimacy, I would look for the designs in Olympia and rigorously stagger competitions and distribute them over a huge complex of arenas: there are places for wrestling and such for runners, there is a horse racing track at the side (that takes space) and maybe a nearby river or lake allows for swimming competitions to be watched from the banks. Since each arena only features a restricted number of watchers, people go and watch the sport they are most interested in.

In an odd suggestion, it might be best to use the general idea of the Circus Maximus and adapt it for the smaller field: a group of playing fields is placed in a line, separated by walls to prevent interference between games. The spectators of each team are placed on one side of the field, the other two sides connect to some sort of mall/public bath/market or the next field. Using pillars at the edge of the field pit, you can add a simple rain or sun roofing. From the market arcades, one can watch down into two playing fields while shopping. The separation of the teams and multiple access points also allow separating hooligans from both sides.

[image: 1-Field element]
The space under the seating and the arena can be used for the team quarters and amenities as well as other needed structures. The picture above shows a rough estimation of a two-fields-element, the smallest element in which it would be constructed. It should be placed alined to a similar height construction on at least one side that serves as both public viewing from the sides (maybe put it between two such elements), shops, and on the ground floors, it might be a good idea to place some public baths. To make the stadium even more intimate, one could skip on the third rank, making each playing field only a 2-ranks construction - and at the same time allow faster and easier construction. Also, the search for the roofing's support beams gets much easier.

For super large events, the separating walls between two arenas could be removed (maybe those are from wood?), and if more than 2 elements have been build adjacent to one another, the removal of several walls could create a racetrack for large events, especially if the last element on one side is a half-round Theater as shown in conjunction here (the top arcades are ignored for making those round is a PITA).
[image: "End" element]

Answer (score 28):

## It's been done:

I'm sorry, but I cannot see how this building does not satisfy your criteria in each and every aspect?

Here an exterior view, showing its grace, spectator comfort, and general Grandeur.
Seating for 75 000. Shaded roof. Good ventilation but shelter from the wind. Food & drink & facilities, the lot. **Including** running water!!

(image from https://www.visionpubl.com/en/cities/rome/the-roman-colosseum/ )
[image]

The arena floor was a covering over the basement levels, where the participants, equipment and mechanisms were housed.
(image from https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/secrets-of-the-colosseum-75827047/ )

[image]

The ONLY missing features, would also be missing in your 16th-century version: Electricity for a lighting and sound system.

Comment: Also: This arena has been used to run **ship battles** in it!

Comment: While the Romans didn't have electricity, they did know a good bit about sound design. Go to any ruin of a colosseum, stand in the center of the arena floor and start speaking. You will be well audible from the entire stadium. They didn't need microphones and speakers. They managed perfectly fine without.

Comment: You could even argue that the Roman Colosseum was **more** advanced than present-day stadiums. I definitely don't know of any baseball stadium that can be turned into a swimming pool!

Comment: @Just'Existing They tend to throw you out if you try.

Comment: @Studoku try in Pula - they have a theatre in that one. Or in Pompeji, where the arena and the (earthen) ranks are fully accessible. Or in any greek amphitheater, which is where the sound design was lifted from.

Comment: @Just'Existing Aren't there some football fields in America that get turned into hockey rinks in the winter? I wouldn't be surprised if it wasn't theoretically possible to turn one into a swimming pool.

Comment: @Just'Existing Yep. Stadiums get converted between football, dirt track racing, stunt jump racing (up to trailer truck size), icerinks, icehockey, zoos, and likely other strange things, too. Never heard of a true swimming pool, as the weight of water is very significant. But a couple of portable swimming pols + air castle obstacle course races is a common sight. I've played golf (including sand traps) in one.

Answer (score 3):

**Move spectators onto the field.**

[image]

Viewers will be moved out onto the playing field!  It is a degree of intimacy never before attempted in the history of sport!  If plexiglas domes are not within the abilities of your people they could have some robust posts acting as a buffer, or they could simply sit at their tables cheering and reaching out to intimately touch the passing players.

As for the players, these spectators would be like a fixed obstacle or sand trap, if hockey had sand traps (it should); to be played around or used strategically.  I can imagine the viewers pulling up their feet as the puck shoots by beneath the table and out the other side.

Yes, there could be collisions and people could get hurt.  Also, passionate fans finding themselves in the thick of things might attempt to help their teams.  Is this so different from the occasional American death caused by a hard hit basketball into the bleachers, or traditional British fans dousing the visiting team with hurled bags of urine?

This novel strategy is redolent of excitement and audience participation.  The stories are writing themselves even as I type!  As regards luxuriant opulence, suffice it to say that this intimate stadium will be opulescently luxuriant, with all of the best stuff from the old stadium copied, improved or stolen from that venue and replaced with risible junk to provoke snorts of contempt by the few visitors that old place might yet attract.